# humidity vs cooling

Tags: cooling, humidity

Which is more efficient? The house is hot, but closed to keep humidity out.  Should we open the doors to let cool air and humidity in or keep closed to keep humidity low, but temperature rises?

Comment: more efficient for what?

Comment: Perhaps the wrong word. Just wondering if I let the cool, high humidity air in, then cool it off, or let the dehumidifier run and heat the house up? Opinions welcome.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Unfortunately, "it  depends on  what you want" is our only possible answer. Please [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how better to contribute here.